# Extract from a groovy file after parsing

Tags: java, groovy

I have the below code `.groovy` file:

```
biodata: {
    "IBM-Ruby" {
      'Expertise= web development',
      'EXperience= 5 years'
    },
    "Microsoft-Dylon"{
      'Expertise= Java',
      'EXperience"= 2 years'
    }
}
```

I am trying to extract only name from the `.groovy` file using tokenizer. For instance I am trying to split `Microsoft-Dylon` from the above `.groovy` file and extract only `Dylon`.

My try at it:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('dataPresent.groovy').toURL())

def NameEach 
    NameEach = config.biodata.each {
    println NameEach 
}
```

Comment: I think the file should be .json instead of .groovy then you can parse the json content.

Comment: Thanks for the input . But its a .groovy file , if u look closely at the quotes . Also I am able to parse it . The problem is to split and extract the name .

Comment: If you are able to parse that file then you just need to split the string by "-" and pick second part of the result. Can you add the expected output in the question?

Comment: Yeah the expected output is : a variable which holds the names as Ruby , Dylon . May be run a loop and fetch each name one by one.

Comment: In my above code if I try to print "config" variable I am getting the parsed data .

Comment: This is neither JSON (no quote on outer key, the most inner lines are either supposed to be an array or that quoting there is wrong) nor Groovy (`:`).

Comment: Yeah correct @cfrick . I have rectified the above file accordingly . Thanks a lot .

Comment: This still is no valid groovy config file (`script15132850782521090859380.groovy: 3: unexpected token: Expertise= web development @ line 3, column 7.`.  Please if you simplify your actual problem, do it in a way the question still makes sense and your inputs are valid.

Answer (score 1):

I have written the following sample groovy code to extract the your expected data as follows by regex, It works.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

String fileContent = new File('/home/user/sampleData.groovy').text
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-([A-Za-z0-9]*)")
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent)
List extractedData = []
while (m.find()) {
    // Adding extracted data to the list
    extractedData << m.group(1).replace("-", "")
}
println extractedData
```

Visit the site (Groovy console) [Groovy console online](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) and just copy and paste the below code there and the hit "Execute script" button.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern
​String text = '''
biodata: {
    "IBM-Ruby" {    
'Expertise= web development',    
'EXperience= 5 years'   
},    
"Microsoft-Dylon"{ 
'Expertise= Java',       
'EXperience"= 2 years'  
} 
}​'''

  String fileContent = text
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-([A-Za-z0-9]*)") 
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent) 
List extractedData = []
while (m.find()) {     
// Adding extracted data to the list    

extractedData << m.group(1).replace("-", "") 
}
println extractedData​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input . But this is not fetching me the correct value . Can you please tell me , how do I fetch the values such as IBM-Ruby , Microsoft-Dylon etc one by one in lets say a loop ...

Comment: You said that you want names after "-". It gives the names

Comment: I get multiple errors and that is the only reason i have not accepted the above answer :

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
GeneratedMarkupTemplate0: 161: unable to resolve class Pattern 
 @ line 161, column 9.
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-([A-Za-z0-9]*)")
           ^

Comment: Do you have the import statements for Matcher and Pattern?

Comment: See I've updated my question, try new code from Groovy console, I've have hard coded file content temporary there.

Comment: See, I have online demo ready here https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5192767730876416

Comment: Yeah , Thanks a lot . But I get the class pattern error here . ANy way to access only the objects such as IBM-Ruby , Microsoft-Dylon etc one by one in a loop . I can then use split() and extract the value . Thanks a lot for the try . I really appreciate it .